# Sync data between ionic3 and Angular5 web application using MangoDB

Tags: ionic3, mean-stack

I am new to ionic mobile app development. Actually currently i creating app and web admin using ionic3 and angular5. I need to choose backend DB inorder to sync data between mobile application and web application. my choice is mangoDB. Can any one give idea for that, Is MangoDB is best option ? Any tutorial for that?. And what are all the procedure to sync using mangoDB ?

Thanks
R.kirubha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First MongoDB will be hosted by central server, so Mongo itself is not enough for your need, you should add backend server to handle http request from your mobile app and you admin site.

MEAN stack is a good choice because it includes Mongo as DB and Node.js/Express as bakend server. It is also quite simple (it stores JSON document as-is, no transformation, javascript only) and well documented. Here is a[tutorial](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/mean-stack)

Alternative to MEAN could be [Google Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/), for which you don't have to code any backend service, it is already available from the storage. However It is cloud service only.